# MVC Google Map Polylines

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps, razor, model-view-controller, google-polyline

I'm trying to create a Google Map that will draw out a race course from a list of lat & lng in my MVC model. I have successfully done this with markers but I need to do it with polylines to create a path of the course. Below is what I have but can't get the lines to show up.

Any suggestions?

```
                                        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=false"></script>
                                    <script>

                                        function initialize() {
                                            var mapOptions = {
                                                zoom: 10,
                                                center: new google.maps.LatLng(@Model.Courses.Latitude, @Model.Courses.Longitude),
                                                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
                                            };

                                            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                                mapOptions);

                                            @foreach (var item in Model.CourseRatings.ValuesList)
                                            {
                                                <text>addMarker(@item.Item2, @item.Item3)</text>
                                            }

                                                var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                                    path: function addMarker(x, y) { new google.maps.LatLng(x, y); },
                                                    geodesic: true,
                                                    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                                                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                                                    strokeWeight: 2
                                                });
                                                flightPath.setMap(map);

                                        }

                                        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

                                    </script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `path` in your `flightPath Polyline`, supply it with an array of your points, rather than a reference to a function. Which should looks something like this:

```
  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
    new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
```

Also consider using the [snap to road api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap) to smoother your polyline.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me but I'm going to try the smoothing you mentioned:

```
                                        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=false"></script>
                                    <script>

                                        function initialize() {
                                            var mapOptions = {
                                                zoom: 10,
                                                center: new google.maps.LatLng(@Model.Courses.Latitude, @Model.Courses.Longitude),
                                                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
                                            };

                                            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                                mapOptions);

                                            var flightPathCoordinates =
                                            [
                                                @foreach (var item in Model.CourseRatings.ValuesList)
                                                {
                                                    <text>new google.maps.LatLng(@item.Item2, @item.Item3),</text>

                                                }
                                            ];

                                            var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                                path: flightPathCoordinates,
                                                geodesic: true,
                                                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                                                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                                                strokeWeight: 2
                                            });
                                            flightPath.setMap(map);

                                        }

                                        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

                                   </script>
```